# Can't run any useful commands in terminal

Tags: linux, terminal, unix

I recently found an Arcom Viper at an auction specifically a VIPER-400-M64-F32 with an ICE enclosure. Upon connecting to the device through its COM port using putty I am greeted with this screen
[image]

From here I can't run any typical Unix or Linux commands

So far the only commands that I have found that do anything are: cd, exit, export, shutdown, reset, sh, pwd

Commands that don't work (No such file or directory): ls, login, mount, mnt, help, ?, basename, echo, env, sudo, id, mkdir, tty, bash, and more

I have tried resetting the path variable using export but the commands still don't work

Additionally on restart path gets reset export shows
PATH=/proc/boot:/bin:./:/
SYSNAME=nto

using the shutdown commands results in the message below, all of those names are recognized by the terminal however I can't seem to do anything with them

[image]

Some weird reset behavior
[image]

**Ultimately my question is how can I get this back to a more usable and traditional Unix/Linux terminal?**

I want to write some arm programs for this thing but I can't seem to get past this stage

If you need any more information or want me to try any commands I am happy to do so! Thanks for your time and your help!

Comment: It might help to try installing a new distribution of Linux on it.

Comment: in case the shell is a very limited posix shell. You could try and discover if there are built-ins and wildcard expansion: `type echo` , `type set` . Then hopefully `echo /*` , `echo /bin/*` etc. Or using `set`: `set -- /*` , `set`.